TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable while running saved model in Tensorflow
I'm new to Tensorflow and Python, I'm running custom object detection in Google Colab and following this tutorial -
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/docs/vision/object_detection.ipynb
and all the steps were running successfully and got saved_model files. Now I'm running the following code to detect the object through webcam (Flask), but I'm getting the following error: Please help me.
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 462, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\response.py", line 50, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "E:\Final project\ran\IP cam\app - Copy (2).py", line 42, in object_detection
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable

Please find my complete code below:
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load("./saved_model/new")
PATH_TO_LABELS = './saved_model/new/label_map.pbtxt'

with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'rb') as f:
    label_map = f.read()

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

def object_detection():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()  # Read frame from webcam
        if not success:
            print("Could not open video device")
            break

        # Perform inference
        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(frame)
        input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]

        detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

        # Visualize the results
        viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
            detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(int),
            detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=200,
            min_score_thresh=0.4,
            agnostic_mode=False)

        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

    cap.release()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(object_detection(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


